# Trying to get Gulp coffeelint to work with coffeelint-stylish

Tags: javascript, gulp, coffeelint

I'm trying to apply stylish error logs to coffeelint, but it doesn't seem to be appearing correctly. I get the following error when I try to apply the plugin

```
Error in plugin 'gulp-coffeelint'
Message:
    coffeelint-stylish is not a valid reporter
```

I have the two plugins required at the top of my gulpfile as follows..
and I obviously have them installed.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');

var coffeelint = require('gulp-coffeelint');
var reporter = require('coffeelint-stylish').reporter;
```

Here is the Task in my Gulpfile.js file

```
gulp.task('coffeelint', function () {
    gulp.src(coffeeSources)
        .pipe(coffeelint())
        .pipe(coffeelint-stylish.reporter())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

```
gulp.task('coflint', function () { gulp.src('components/coffee/*.coffee') .pipe(coffeelint()) .pipe(coffeelint.reporter('default')) });
```

The 'default' uses coffeelint-stylish